# ES6: Can i init variable with value of the result of destruction of an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

So, what i have:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const { a, c } = obj;
const newObj = { a, c };
//newObj is { a: 1, c: 3 } now
```

What i kinda want to have:

```
const newObj = { a, c } = obj
//newObj is { a: 1, c: 3 } now
```

Looks much cleaner for big objects (but dont work, obviously).
Any ideas?

Summary: lodash.pick mentioned by @wostex is best solution for now

Comment: lodash.pick maybe?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do anything similar since the return value of `let a,c;{a, c} = obj` is `obj` and not an anonymous temporary object `{ a, c }`

Comment: @wostex nice one, but it would be more elegant with raw js if possible

Comment: Upcoming ES2018 has [rest properties destructuring](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html). It's the other way around tho, object from props not mentioned instead of object from props mentioned. Until then, lodash.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particularly clean way to do this. I do it with an inline function by leveraging parameter destructuring:

`const newObj = (({a,b,c})=>({a,b,c}))(originalObj)`

The downside to this solution is that it is not dynamic. You can not, for example, create a `pluck` function that retrieves a dynamic list of properties using this.

Comment: Chrome console:
var originalObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const newObj = (({a,b,c})=>(a,b,c))(originalObj);
console.log(newObj);

// output is '3'
No idea how that happened

Comment: @DmitriiS. I had a typo that I have fixed